# Vertical bundle and tangent bundle of the fiber

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

For a fiber bundle $\pi: E\rightarrow B$ with typical fiber a manifold $F$, we define the vertical subbundle $V$ by the exact sequence of verctor bundles over $E$:
$$0\rightarrow V\rightarrow TE \rightarrow \pi^*TB\rightarrow0.$$
In the case when $F$ has a Lie group structure and $E$ is a principal bundle, we know that $V$ is the trivial bundle with fiber $T_eF$, the Lie algebra of $F$.

In general, can we say anything about $V$ and $TF$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trivial in general. For example, the Klein bottle $K$ is the total space of a fibre bundle $S^1 \to K \xrightarrow{\pi} S^1$. Note that $\pi^*TS^1$ is trivial and if $V$ were isomorphic to $TS^1$, it would also be trivial. This would imply that $TK$ is trivial, but this is not the case as $K$ is non-orientable.

Let $i : F \to E$ be the inclusion of a fiber. Since $\pi\circ i$ is constant, we see that $0 = (\pi\circ i)_* = \pi_*\circ i_*$, so $i_*TF \subseteq \ker \pi_* = V$. By comparing ranks, we see that in fact $i_*TF = V$ and hence $TF \cong i^*V$.

Comment: Thanks! Just for a quick sanity check: set $j:E\rightarrow F$ to be the projection such that $j\circ i=\mathrm{id}$. Does that imply $V=j^*TF$?

Comment: There is no such map $j$ in general. For example, consider the bundle $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to S^1 \to S^1$ (the non-trivial double cover of $S^1$). Any (continuous) map $j : S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is constant, so $j \circ i$ is constant and hence not equal to $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$.

Comment: Oh that's a nice point. If the fiber is assumed to be connected, would that makes $V$ a pullback?

Comment: No. Consider the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$. Note that $j\circ i$ is nullhomotopic as $S^3$ is simply connected, so it cannot be equal to $\operatorname{id}_{S^1}$ as $S^1$ is not contractible.